# Pushing UIViewController into another UIViewController with a fixed free size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I need to push a UIViewController into another one, the one that will pushed has size 320 width,300 height.

When I try to push, neither pushViewController:animated nor presentViewController:animated:completion: pushes on to whole page.

I have reached my goal by view containment, but it is not a good practice for me.

What other methods i can apply?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to push a view controller onto another one, you should probably be using a Navigation Controller. I'm kind of unsure as to if this is something you have thought of, but a UINavigationController would be ideal in this case, because it would allow you to push/pop your view controllers on/off the stack.

Comment: Usage of UINavigationController does not matter, the important point is pushing 320*300 sized viewcontroller on to another's specific place